# Combine animations instead of blend?

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm importing animations on a skinned mesh from a glTF created in Blender to THREE.js
I have two simultaneous animations that affect the translation of a bone. In Blender, these translations are summed, but in THREE.js they're averaged by weight.

For example, the animations are translate(2, 0, 0) and translate(4, 0, 0)
How do I get the AnimationMixer to result in (6, 0, 0) instead of (3, 0, 0)?

Comment: Could you say more about what you're trying to do with summed animations? I'm not sure three.js supports this exactly but maybe there are some options.

Comment: I'm trying to have character with customizable size. If its chest is wider, I'll need his arms farther apart; if his legs longer, I'll need his arms higher, etc. Problem is if they're both active, then it's only half farther apart and half as high.
I can create the translations within three.js instead of as animations, but I was hoping to be able to use what I've already made in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

For my specific needs, I really only needed the values from the first and last frames (they're all 3 frame animations with the second being default values). So I pull the values from the keyframe tracks, and won't use the animation system at all.
      //converts animations to values
      fuction convertAnim( clips ){

```
    var anims = [];

      for ( i = 0; i < clips.length; i ++ ){

      anims[i] = {name: "name", bone: []};
      anims[i].name = clips[i].name;

        for ( j = 0; j < clips[i].tracks.length; j++ ){

            var val = clips[i].tracks[j].values

            if ( clips[i].tracks[j].name.indexOf( 'position' ) > -1 ) {
                anims[i].bone[j] = { name: "name", minTranslate: "min", maxTranslate: "max"};
                anims[i].bone[j].name = clips[i].tracks[j].name;

                anims[i].bone[j].minTranslate = new THREE.Vector3( val[0], val[1], val[3] );
                anims[i].bone[j].maxTranslate = new THREE.Vector3( val[val.length - 3], val[val.length - 2], val[val.length - 1] );
            }

            else if ( clips[i].tracks[j].name.indexOf( 'scale' ) > -1 ) {
                anims[i].bone[j] = { name: "name", minSize: "min", maxSize: "max"};
                anims[i].bone[j].name = clips[i].tracks[j].name;

                anims[i].bone[j].minSize = new THREE.Vector3( val[0], val[1], val[2] );
                anims[i].bone[j].maxSize = new THREE.Vector3( val[val.length - 3], val[val.length - 2], val[val.length - 1] );
            }

            else if ( clips[i].tracks[j].name.indexOf( 'scale' ) > -1 ) {
                anims[i].bone[j] = { name: "name", minRotation: "min", maxRotation: "max"};
                anims[i].bone[j].name = clips[i].tracks[j].name;

                anims[i].bone[j].minRotation = new THREE.Quaternion( val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3] );
                anims[i].bone[j].maxRotation = new THREE.Quaternion( val[val.length -4], val[val.length - 3], val[val.length - 2], val[val.length - 1] );
            }           
        }
      }

    return anims;

  }
```